# dynamic css using "macros"

Tags: javascript, css

I have a CSS file that is going to populate some divs with background images.

```
.span3.one {
   background: url('//path/to/images') 
}

.span4.one {
   background: url('//path/to/images') 
} 

span5.one {
   background: url('//path/to/images')
}
```

Can there be some macro or such that dynamically replaces some string based on various conditions like what domain/url the request originated or some clue in the link that called the page?

```
span3.one {
   background: url('//$replacemoreintelligently') 
}
```

I would rather use node.js or python, not PHP if server side is the answer. I just need some direction on this though.

There would potentially be thousands of these pages.
Thank you.

Comment: If you need thousands of unique CSS definitions you may have a design problem.  You can probably generate all the CSS you'd ever want with JavaScript, but I think you need to be questioning why you need  thousands of background imagef.

Comment: There's http://lesscss.org and http://sass-lang.com/. Frankly, anytime you have that kind of permutation of granularity, you should take a step or two back and rethink the overall approach.

Comment: also http://learnboost.github.com/stylus/

Comment: yes, my design im pretty sure is flawed...but just to get a prototype of an idea in code. I must start somewhere. my thinking was use one html page and allow it to be styled with in a myriad of ways. javascript is my hurdle...now i must study..pls do pass on any info on more efficent css utilization. thx u

Answer (score 0):

I think you would want to use [Less](http://lesscss.org/).